# invalid parameter in nginx.conf

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server

when i run

> sudo  nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t

i get this message

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "if=$loggable" in 
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:33
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

and this is my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

     access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
#    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
#    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main buffer=size flush=time;


    # Custom Log Owner
    map $status $loggable {
            ~^2  1;
            default 0;
    }

    log_format owner_log '{"owner_id":"$arg_owner_id","status":"$status","bytes":"$body_bytes_sent","created":"$time_local"}';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/owner.log owner_log if=$loggable;


    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_requests 10000;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx_inmobly_sdk.conf;
}
```

and all my logs file are belong to nginx user 
i can't recognize that is the problem 
i use ubuntu 
what is default permission for logs file ?
which user  should run nginx

Comment: What is the `nginx` version?

Comment: nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Comment: The `if` parameter was added in a later version. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log).